# pandas filter rows based on atmost matching criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, filter

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'subjects':['A','A','D','B','B','C'],
                'B':['12','12','13','14','14','16'],
                'C':[21,23,24,25,26,27]
                })
df['r_no'] = df.groupby(['subjects','B']).cumcount()+1
```

Now, I would like to only **select rows that had only `r_no = 1`** (and not r_no > 1).

I tried the below

```
df[df['subjects'].value_counts() == 1]
df.iloc[df['subjects'].value_counts() == 1:,]
df.ix[df['subjects'].value_counts() == 1:,]
df[(df['r_no'] == 1) & (df['r_no'] < 2)]
```

None of them worked.

I expect my output to be like as shown below.

You can see that `subjects = A` and `subjects = B` is excluded because they also had rows where `r_no` > 1.  Basically, I want to select subjects that had only one record for them (r_no) in dataframe

[image]

Comment: @wwnde No, this will result in incorrect output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, what you want to do it just to keep the groups of size 1:

```
df[df.groupby(['subjects','B'])['C'].transform(len).le(1)]
```

Or maybe even just keeping the subjects with unique rows:

```
df[~df['subjects'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

output:

```
  subjects   B   C
2        D  13  24
5        C  16  27
```

Comment: but does it do what you want? ;)

Comment: this doesn't mean it does what you want, for instance the two approaches wouldn't yield the same result if subject A also has a different B value

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df.groupby('subjects')['r_no'].transform(lambda x: ~(x.ne(1).any()))]



   subjects   B   C  r_no
2        D  13  24     1
5        C  16  27     1
```